# Changed the IP address of my ad dc

Tags: windows, networking, windows-server-2012-r2

so I had these 2 servers, the first one is my AD DC and the second one is my WDS server which is joined to the domain.

- I changed the IP address of my DC from x.x.1.52 to x.x.1.88
- On my WDS server, when I try to ping it via hostname it looks up for the x.x.1.52 and when I ping it via the IP address, it says RTO.
- On my DC Server, I tried to scavenge stale dns, nltest /dsregdns and even doubled checked A record, it is already showing the x.x.1.88 ip address.
- Going back to WDS Server, I already flushed the dns and double checked the hosts file, nothing was manually mapped (if I put the fqdn - ip of my DC server, it works)

So just wanna know if there's a way to fix it without doing the last option I did.. Thanks!!

Comment: You binging a flat name or a FQDN name? what does nslookup say? flush NetBIOS too using "nbtstat -R" and go a head and reboot the DC if haven't done so already to update everything, specially DNS records.

Comment: Hello, OK I did restart both servers, I can ping x.x.1.88 from my WDS server but if I try to ping hostname or fqdn still nothing.. by the way, the primary DNS of my WDS server is x.x.1.88

Comment: is ICMP enabled on DC? did you check DNS for any rouge records related to DC? what does NSlookup say?

Comment: Hi, yes, ICMP ipv4/v6 are both enabled, nothing was filtered on their properties. tried to nslookup on DC, and it only shows my default gateway. Nslookup on WDS server shows DNS request timed out.

Comment: Check the properties of the DNS server on your DC and make sure it's listening on the new ip address. Also verify that the network and firewall profiles on both machines shows as Domain. Also make sure to change the DNS server settings on the NIC of the DC to reflect the new ip address of the DC.

Comment: Hi, I'm not sure but I think my DC server works well as the zone of my wds server is still there, by the way, both server are connected to a single vEthernet (external).

Comment: Did you update the DNS settings on DNS nic to point to the new DNS server IP...

Comment: Jim Stevens, your comments aren't making sense. In your question you say you assigned a static ip address but in your comment you say that both servers have a DHCP assigned ip address. Which is it? Did you follow the steps in my comment?

Comment: Hi, Apologies for the late revert, please disregard my previous comment. Nevertheless, is it correct that on my WDS Server, I'll put in the ip address of my DC as it's primary dns?

Comment: Hi Guys, thanks for all the help, I really appreciate the community here :) it's working now :) you may refer to pxed's answer :) learned a lot today :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you have some DNS clean up to do. The article below gives a high-level of changes, but really what I would recommend doing is to open DNS and go through every section, and wherever you see x.x.1.52, change it to x.x.1.88. Then flush the cache on the server and flush the cache on the host that's not resolving. [[Link here](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-server-2008-R2-and-2008/cc794931(v=ws.10))]

Secondly, if you are in an environment with multiple DCs, it's also important to make sure that replication is still working - you can check this by running the command `repadmin /showrepl`. In addition to this being bad for your environment, if your domain controllers aren't able to communicate the changes you made in one DNS server most likely aren't syncing, which could also cause your symptoms if your WDS server is using the secondary DC that hasn't gotten the change. If that's the case, perform the DNS cleanup on the second DC and try replicating again. [More info on Repadmin [here](http://blog.backslasher.net/viewing-detailed-replication-status-using-repadmin-and-powershell.html) and [here](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc773062(v=ws.10).aspx)]

Lastly, it doesn't look like you changed the subnet, but if you did, don't forget to also update the subnet in sites and services. [An overview of sites and services can be found [here](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/canitpro/2015/03/03/step-by-step-setting-up-active-directory-sites-subnets-site-links/)]

Let us know if you still are seeing issues after the clean-up!

Comment: Hi, thank you for taking time on this matter, I'll look into this as well and ensure to follow the steps you gave me :)

Comment: Anytime! Let me know if you run into any issues, or if you have any questions along the way

Comment: Hi Guys, I've tried some of the suggestions here, such as double checking the DNS, and yeah, some of the A records and NS records still show .52, so I changed it .88. I'm not sure if I missed some more things but when i do ns lookup from my WDS server, it doesn't get it, even pinging the fqdn or hostname (this gives me still .52).. I might missed something here. By the way, if I click resolve on NS records, it shows 2 valid (including the .88) and it still gives me .52(the old IP).

Comment: Hi Guys, thank you for all the help. This solution worked. I guess I commented to early and did not wait enough for it to replicate and re-register the dns. This is now fixed :)Thank you pxed :)

Answer (score 0):

First of all you should run `ipconfig /registerdns` on the domain controller, after you changed its IP address. Have you done this?
What does `nslookup fqdn_of_your_dc` show on your WDS?

Comment: Hello, I'll try this one as soon as I'm back on it and I'll re-try the nslookup on my wds..